# Word to describe a person who tolerates other people's mistakes

Tags: single-word-requests

A close friend of mine is a tech support and I'd like to give him card and compliment on his tolerance for (sometimes silly) mistakes.

I'm looking for a word to describes a person that tolerates others' mistakes. For example, this person might be a school teacher who wouldn't be angry because a kid made a mistake or a boss in a company who wouldn't get mad because his or her employees messed up.

**I'm looking for something other than tolerant** because I would like to be specific and narrow down the scope to be just tolerant towards mistakes.

On the other hand, I feel words like *nice*, *patient*, and the like all entail some level of tolerance towards others' mistakes. Moreover, this quality of tolerance for mistakes doesn't necessarily entail that this person is nice or friendly. It may be because it's his job and he's a competent employee. I may be wrong and this's way too specific, but I wonder if there's a word depicts exactly that.

Either noun or adjective will work! I just want it to be one word so it looks good on the cover of the card!

Comment: I'd just say patient.

Comment: If I were grading or appraising someone's work, like a teacher or a judge, and I were prone to handing out high marks even though there were obvious mistakes, I might say lenient.

Comment: forbearing, understanding, accepting....

Comment: If you don’t want to come right out and call him what he really is (a saint), I’d suggest describing such a person as “[long-suffering](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/long-suffering).”

Comment: see if "stoic" fits. Stoic people calmly go with the flow and don't appear to be shook up by much.

Comment: It just comes to tolerant and its synonyms. I don't think there is a specific word for "just tolerant towards mistakes".

Comment: @Dare or "very forgiving."

Comment: While I'm not familiar with specific words that'll adequately capture the sentiment, there are a few idioms/simile that might suffice such as *the patience of a corpse/saint* or  *the stoicism of a Russian Grandmother*

Comment: "enabler" ?! :)   What about just "tolerant", that's fine

Comment: When applied to *people*, you probably can't avoid at least *overtones* of the literal meaning, but a [***forgiving** technique*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22forgiving+technique%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), for example, aptly describes a method which figuratively "tolerates" mistakes yet still achieves the intended result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[longanimous](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/longanimous)** or **[forbearing](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/forbearing)**

> showing patient and unruffled self-control and restraint under adversity; **slow to retaliate or express resentment**

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: I find myself upvoting every single one of your answers. And half the time I'm not even aware it's you until I'm done voting and scroll to the bottom of the answer and see your username.

Comment: @DanBron: Well I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: That's just spot on, sir Raj! [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/longanimity): patient endurance of hardship, injuries, or offense; forbearance.

Comment: @RexYuan: Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 1):

"Patient and understanding" is best in this case

thank you for your patience and understanding

the other answers I  see here are better expressions of your meaning, but this is more appropriate to your usage

Answer (score 0):

You could also use "perseverant":

> Able or willing to persevere : enduring